# Is there a dagger equivalent to Guice's getInstance() in Dagger?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice, dagger-2

I was wondering if there was a way to get an instance of a class in Dagger kind of like in Guice. For example, if I have the following in Guice:

```
import com.google.inject.Injector;

public ClassX {
  Injector injector;  

  @Inject
  public ClassX (Injector injector) {
    this.injector = injector;
  }

  methodA(){
    final IServerConfig serverConfig = injector.getInstance(SomeClass.class);
  }

}
```

How could I imitate `injector.getInstance(SomeClass.class)` in Dagger?

Thank you!

Comment: Is injector supposed to give a singleton for SomeClass?

Comment: Why are you coupling your code to Guice features like that instead of just using CDI and injecting a member variable of type `SomeClass`?   I don't understand your use case.   But if you really want to build the graph programmatically somewhere for some reason, see the section "Building The Graph" in the Dagger docs: https://dagger.dev/dev-guide/  (TLDR: you don't inject an "Injector" class, you use a special auto-generated interface `Dagger<MyType>`)